# MigraDoc Adding Watermarks Issue

Tags: vb.net, pdf, migradoc

I have created a PDF document via MigraDoc and so far all has gone well.  The final stage is to add a watermark for 'drafts' for which I have found a few examples but I just can't seem to get them to work!

I create a section as normal

```
section = document.AddSection()
section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.A4
```

...and then add the watermark using

```
Sub AddWatermark(section As Section)
    Dim imageFile = Server.MapPath("./images/draft.png")
    Dim myImage = section.Headers.EvenPage.AddImage(imageFile)
    myImage.Height = Unit.FromMillimeter(100)
    myImage.LockAspectRatio = True
    myImage.Top = Shapes.ShapePosition.Center
    myImage.Left = Shapes.ShapePosition.Center
    myImage.RelativeHorizontal = Shapes.RelativeHorizontal.Margin
    myImage.RelativeVertical = Shapes.RelativeVertical.Margin
    myImage.WrapFormat.Style = Shapes.WrapStyle.Through
End Sub
```

I then create the rest of the document which is mainly a table and output to the browser.  It all works and I have stepped through in debug to ensure the image is picked up and no exceptions but the output PDF doesn't have a watermark.  I've tried different images, sizes etc but nothing seems to actually add the watermark so any ideas welcome!

Comment: Yes I did try to use the PdfSharp example as that would have allowed text to be used as the watermark but I had some difficulties translating it from C# to VB.NET - my expertise is C# but the application I am working on is VB which I am no expert in to be sure.

Comment: I have however finally got it to work.  The critical thing appears to be adding the image to the section header - the above code does not work however if I change it to 

Dim header As HeaderFooter = section.Headers.Primary
Dim myImage = header.AddImage(imageFile)

The watermark appears - it appears the original sample is incorrect as it does not set the image in the Primary Header of the Section which in my case is necessary.

Comment: The `EvenPage` headers are used for even pages if you activate a double-page layout. `Primary` is used for all pages in a single-page layout (unless you specify different first-page headers).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in my case the critical point is that when I set the image it needs to be set in 'section.Headers.Primary'. Setting in Even Page only seems to work if you have different even and odd pages and seems to be ignored otherwise.  Anyone after a VB.NET solution please see below as this works for me and I hadn't found a VB solution elsewhere

```html
Sub AddWatermark(section As Section)
  Dim imageFile = Server.MapPath("./images/draft.png")
  Dim header As HeaderFooter = section.Headers.Primary
  Dim myImage = header.AddImage(imageFile)
  myImage.Height = Unit.FromMillimeter(200)
  myImage.LockAspectRatio = True
  myImage.Top = Shapes.ShapePosition.Center
  myImage.Left = Shapes.ShapePosition.Center
  myImage.RelativeHorizontal = Shapes.RelativeHorizontal.Margin
  myImage.RelativeVertical = Shapes.RelativeVertical.Margin
  myImage.WrapFormat.Style = Shapes.WrapStyle.Through
 End Sub
```